# How to web scrape a number with python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to web scrape a simple number from this [website](https://www.quantalys.com/Recherche?Values.lstCategorie=27&Values.lstIdProduits=1&Values.bExcludeUncommercialized=true&Values.bETF=true)

I tried this code but get an empty variable:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.quantalys.com/Recherche?Values.lstCategorie=27&Values.lstIdProduits=1&Values.bExcludeUncommercialized=true&Values.bETF=true"
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")
nbre = soup.find("DataTables_Table_0_info")
nbre
```

[image]

Comment: Use selenium...

Comment: Data is fetched via separate call and updated to the html once that call has been done. You cannot just pass a browser url to requests/bs4 and hope for the best..  Like Daviid said above, use selenium or similar or learn how the web works and use the same endpoint as the webpage itself is using to fetch the data.

Comment: Agreed with @Daviid. You can grab cell data with beautifulsoup no issues with that. But when you want to grab header,footer,pagecontrol values selenium is the best tool to do it.

Comment: That does not help me ! How to get this number with selenium ?

Comment: @MahboobNur  that's not true and not my point, as @rasjani said, data is fetched via javascript, if you check the source code of the page, `DataTables_Table_0_info` doesn't even exist, which means data is fetched via ajax and the table is then built. This is very easy to see if you check the network tab in the browser's dev tools. Not sure why you would say something that is not true.

Comment: Just check the network tab in the browser's dev tools, the endpoint is https://www.quantalys.com/Recherche/Data , don't expect someone here to write your code for you.

Answer (score 1):

Use Selenium instead of requests, As site is loading data through JavaScript and request lib, doesn't return JavaScript response.
**Make sure you have downloaded the correct chromedriver version of your chromebrowser and kept it at local dir from where you are running the script**

Below is the code that will help:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
url = 'https://www.quantalys.com/Recherche?Values.lstCategorie=27&Values.lstIdProduits=1&Values.bExcludeUncommercialized=true&Values.bETF=true'
driver.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,'html.parser')
nbre = soup.find('div',id='DataTables_Table_0_info').text.strip()
print(nbre)
```

Output:
5,277 élément(s)